# Control Elements Visibility from other class/viewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am development an app using xamarin forms, and I am trying to build an animated menu, this is what I have used

1. I created a `ContentView` and put buttons there and created complete animations there (because same `contentview` will be used on multiple screens)
   animation works fine but buttons can not be clicked after they changed their position using TranslateTo method in xamarin.
2. My idea was to use another hidden layout with  buttons on same positions where animated buttons will appear at end, but these button will have 0 opacity this means they will work properly but not visible to user, and when menu gone hidden this layout should be hidden too

**The Problem:** When I click on menu button animated menu appears correct but I am unable to make other layout visible or hide,

I am not sure if we can hide/show elements from other classes other then View's on class, this what I am trying to achieve.

Here is little sample of my code:

Menus.cs (this is my ContentView which I am using in Detail.cs)

```
Detail d = new Detail();
d.ToggleBtnLayout();
```

I am using this method in Menu.cs to show/hide a layout which is inside Detail.cs.

Comment: we need to see more code to help, but generally there is no reason you can't control visibility from another class.  In the snippet you show you appear to be creating a new instance of Detail instead of referencing the instance that already exists on screen.